# What kind of visa should i get to participate in UK entrepreneurship programs?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, startups

I am a citizen of Iran. I like to participate in some UK startup programs like this https://www.joinef.com. It's a 4 months program, that individuals can participate and find a co-founder to establish a new startup/company. So I think I must get a visitor visa(tourist visa), then change it to entrepreneur or startup visa.

If I am right, please let me know, can I change my tourist visa to entrepreneur visa or startup visa or any other work visa in England or I must come back to Iran and apply for new visa again?!

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: Have you checked [the requirements](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/eligibility) for the Tier 1 (entrepreneur) visa? Do you meet them?

Comment: @MJeffryes: I like to apply for graduate entrepreneur visa. And if I could get the fund in a incubation program I will apply for this visa!

Comment: @MJeffryes: As I mentioned in my question, I like to participate in startup programs, then if i could find some co-founders and get funded and decided to establish a company, I will change my visa to graduate entrepreneur visa. But I don't know is it possible inside the UK or not? If not, I think I must forget it.

Comment: @MJeffryes: you provided a very nice link in my other question that i deleted (https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/switch-to-this-visa), in the last line is written: `a visitor who has been carrying out permitted activities as a prospective entrepreneur`. So I think I can do what I liked to do, but I am not sure. May you explain more about this option if you know? BEST Regards.

Comment: @Hasini Presumably the startup programme you're applying to will know the answer to these questions. I think you will get better information by asking them. This is a specialised area of immigration law, and if you have access to >£50,000 in investment then you can presumably afford a solicitor.